# How to add Qty in add to cart form on Product Listings Page in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, theme, template, addtocart

How can you add a Qty filed to the the add to cart form on the category listings page.

With the Luma theme the user only has the option to add one product to cart at a time from the product listings page:

[image]

Is there a way I can edit the form in my theme at: `app/design/frontend/Holy/mytheme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml`

```
<form data-role="tocart-form" action="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $postParams['action']; ?>" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="product" value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $postParams['data']['product']; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED; ?>" value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $postParams['data'][Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED]; ?>">
    <?php echo $block->getBlockHtml('formkey')?>
    <button type="submit"
            title="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Cart')); ?>"
            class="action tocart primary">
        <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Add to Cart') ?></span>
    </button>
</form>
```

For now it would work even if I could just do this for simple products.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

On this form just add below code

> ```
> <input type="number"
> name="qty"
> id="qty"
> maxlength="12"
> value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo '1' ?>"
> title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Qty') ?>" class="input-text qty" />
> ```

and check what is happen :)

Comment: wow, that was much easier than I expected. Thanks! By chance do you know how to add the same for the related products on the product details page?  In `app/design/frontend/Holy/mytheme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list/items.phtml`

Comment: I have not been able to update cart with this line present in the phtml

Comment: Do you now how can i programatically update the value of input

Comment: @Amit Bera can you please help me on this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/201931/configurable-not-adding-to-cart-in-magento2-1-9?noredirect=1#comment279795_201931

Comment: Do you know how can I add Qty in add to cart form on configurable Product Listings Page in Magento 2.3

Comment: @Amitbera will this add qty in cart also?

Comment: Great job, thanks Amit.

Answer (score 1):

```
in the form of add to cart just add this code 

<?php echo $block->getBlockHtml('formkey')?>
<input type="number"
                       name="qty"
                       id="qty"
                       maxlength="12"
                       value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getProductDefaultQty() * 1 ?>"
                       title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Qty') ?>" class="input-text qty form-control"
                       data-validate="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(json_encode($block->getQuantityValidators())) ?>"
                       />
<button type="submit" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Add to Cart') ?>" class="action btn-add-cart tocart">
<i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>
<span class="text"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Add to Cart') ?></span>
</button>
```

Comment: $block->getProductDefaultQty() & $block->getQuantityValidators() does not work on list page, otherwise this should be better answer.