# How to add Qty Field on Product Listings Page in Magento 2

Tags: magento2

I want to add Qty field on product list page when I have change qty on textbox then qty is updated after add to cart button click. mini cart qty is changed.

**Expected Output**
[image]

Comment: Please check this link : https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/170117/55702