# Magento 2: How to add quantity field in category page

Tags: magento2, category, category-products, quantity

I need to add quantity box in category page. your help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Refer the below : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/170114/how-to-add-qty-in-add-to-cart-form-on-product-listings-page-in-magento-2