# How to add Qty Input to product list WIDGET

Tags: magento2, widgets, magento2.3.0, qty

How can you add Qty Input to product list **Widget** in Magento 2.
*(not the the product list page as described [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/170117/6549))*

1. I have added a product list widget to a CMS page like by clicking on the insert widget button and filling in the widget form.
   [image]
2. This adds the Product List to the CMS page. 
   [image]
3. I would like it to include a QTY input so the user cans select how many products they wish to add to the cart...
   [image]

I'm able to add the QTY input by adding the code below to [here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3/app/code/Magento/CatalogWidget/view/frontend/templates/product/widget/content/grid.phtml#L73).

It appears fine, but the issue is that it does not add the select qty by the user, it only ever adds one item at a time.

This seems to be because of how the button is adding the item to the cart...

```
<button class="action tocart primary" data-post="{&quot;action&quot;:&quot;https:\/\/example.com\/checkout\/cart\/add\/uenc\/aHR0cHM6Ly9xYS5zYW1tY2NhdWxleS5jb20vdGVzdC1wYWdlMg%2C%2C\/product\/39\/&quot;,&quot;data&quot;:{&quot;product&quot;:&quot;39&quot;,&quot;uenc&quot;:&quot;aHR0cHM6Ly9xYS5zYW1tY2NhdWxleS5jb20vdGVzdC1wYWdlMg,,&quot;}}" type="button" title="Add to Cart">
<span>Add to Cart</span>
</button>
```

Any idea of how I can update the product list widget so that it can have a qty field which works.

Comment: Same question here, did you solved? @Holly

Answer (score 0):

by default luma theme don't allow to add qty .. you can try other theme..