# How to add Qty in add to cart form on Product Listings Page for configurable product in Magento 2

Tags: magento2.3.1, qty, product-listing

I want to add Qty field on product list page for configurable product and simple product. I am using Magento 2.3.1
can you guide me how can I do?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add input in your `form`.

You can put it on above `Add to cart`.

You can add in below file:

> app/design/frontend/{Package}/{theme}/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml

```
<input type="number" name="qty" id="qty" maxlength="12" value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo '1' ?>" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Qty') ?>" class="input-text qty" />
```

Hope above will help!

[Reference](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/170114/how-to-add-qty-in-add-to-cart-form-on-product-listings-page-in-magento-2/170117#170117)

Comment: I use this code but it works only for simple product but I want to display configurable product as well.

Comment: I checked it is working for configurable as well!

Comment: List.phtml is applicable for both

Comment: Hi Pawan, 
I want text box for each size.please see attached screenshot:
https://imghostr.com/F2QnsQgR

Comment: I need to add multiple products with multiple sizes on the Category page at once?

Comment: @kiran, in OP you asked to add input to list page. If you want input for each size, you need to create a custom controller and need to add product programmatically.

Comment: Can you guide me please how can I create custom controller?

Comment: did you manage to add input box to size ? if yes, please share code.

Comment: https://imghostr.com/8DzDwQXd -category page, I want same feature.
https://imghostr.com/p1TgjdTk ---product page is working